# How can I update a value in mapped list without updating the list's siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a React hook to fetch data from a products API. I have 4 columns for the following: Item, Quantity, Unit price, and Sub total. The Sub total is the sum of Quantity and Unit price. I want a situation where if I change the Quantity, the Sub total of that particular product will update to reflect the change. However, when I try that, the Sub total of all the products are updated. My function that updates the Quantity is the `handleChange` function.

How do I increase or decrease the quantity of a single product without altering that of other products?

```
function App() {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1)

  const [numbers] = useState([
    {label: 1, value: 1},{label: 2, value: 2},{label: 3, value: 3},{label: 4, value: 4},
  ]);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuantity(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  useEffect(() => { 
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>ITEM</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">QUANTITY</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">UNIT PRICE</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">SUBTOTAL</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {items.map((item) => (
              <TableRow key={item.id}>
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {item.title}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                  <select onChange={handleChange}>
                    {numbers.map(number => (
                      <option
                        key={number.value}
                        value={number.value}
                      >
                        {number.label }
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </select>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.price}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.price * quantity}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <button type="button">Delete</button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    <div className={classes.checkout}>Checkout</div>
    </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like your quantity hook is of type number and you're applying that number to every row. Instead, what you could do is when you receive your result from api, map over  the array of items and add quantity property to each item.

Comment: Alright. Let me try that now.

Comment: I did that now. The quantity property updates as I want, but it still affects the Sub total of all the products.
I want it to only update the Sub total of just 1 product.

Comment: See answer below. Should be all the changes you need to make to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quantity property to each item in items array.

```
  useEffect(() => { 
    fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          let updatedItems = result.map((item) => {
              item["quantity"] = 0;
              return item;
          });
          setItems(updatedItems);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
```

Modify your handleChange function to take in item id as a second argument

```
<select onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,item.id)}>
```

Use id to change the quantity of the right item object

```
const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    let updatedItems = items.map(item => {
          if(item.id === id){
              item.quantity = e.target.value
          }
          return item
    }
   setItems(updateItems)
  }
```

Correctly multiply price and quantity

```
<TableCell align="right">{item.price * item.quantity}</TableCell>
```

Comment: It did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.